# How change in TWO child component can result in change in Parent component's Output?

Tags: json, angular, checkbox, filter

Here I have college task to do..where i got stuck in the middle.! I have two child component one is having the checkboxes to filter the result while one has the detail of the output to be display.Now I am done with the outer part i.e. layout but now getting confused how to imply its functions and all, guys please help me with this as i am doing this since last 1 and half days.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulaar-aman?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

here is the work i have done till now..!!

Comment: Pass filtered value into `change` event of checkbox and then send this value to `parent`, In parent get that value and filter your data

Comment: What are you trying to do? Based on checked items in one child component show the resultant output in another child component? Is this the task?

Comment: @emkay yes the list which is to be display is in one child and the filter is in another one..!! and both are connected to one parent component

Comment: @AbdulBasit but parent component is just to display both the child component..the actual content is in both the child component  so how can i do this?? please explain in detail a bit..

Answer (score 1):

When any change happens in the checkbox child component, evaluate what all checkboxes are checked and pass that through event emitter. Using that data you can all the method of detail child component using template reference variable . Try that. I have made some changes in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulaar-aman-7uykyh).
Let's simplify your structure as:-

```
<app-parent>
 <child-checkbox (checkedValues)="showFreshDetails($event,details)"></child-box>
 <child-details  #details></child-details>
</app-parent>
```

In above code, what I am doing is that when any check uncheck happen in child-checkbox component, you emit values reprsenting that, for example a json, of type

```
[{'option1':checked},{'option2':unchecked})]
```

Now inside showFreshDetails(json,details) (defined in parent component) you are passing this json and also the **template reference variable** of child-details component. Here it's defined as #details on child-details component. 
Inside the showFreshDetails(), you call a method of child-details component, for examp;le showNewDetails() using the **template reference variable** details, you can pass the json you emitted to that method as well if you wish.

Comment: i didnt quite got you..sorry can you brief me about it please

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulaar-aman?file=src%2Fapp%2Fjobdetails%2Fjobdetails.component.ts  i have updated it right now i started it with a new start and just tried to connect one child to another have look na please.

Comment: What changes have you made in the stackblitz? Looks same to me.

Comment: Also I have updated the answer, see if you can understand it or should I provide more explaination.

Comment: i have simplified a bit now i am emiting the value from child-checkbox-component and trying to catch it in the other component..can you please have a look on this..as i guess there need to be some sought of link between both the child component..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulaar-aman?file=src%2Fapp%2Fjobdetails%2Fjobdetails.component.html

Comment: changes are like now i have not touched parent.ts just working on both childs .ts

Comment: If you are emitting from a child component, you can capture it only in parent component and not the sibling component. Captured data will have to go through parent component and then to another child component. 
Please go through this stackblitz properly, you will understand how to transfer data from one child component to another. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzrqes